# Using wkhtmltopdf with dynamic templates

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

I want to generate a PDf of a django template / view; that uses templatetags etc.

From django-wkhtmltopdf's documentation:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, patterns
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='my_template.html',
                                           filename='my_pdf.pdf'), name='pdf'),
)
```

Or they say in your own view:

```
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView


class MyPDF(PDFTemplateView):
    filename = 'my_pdf.pdf'
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    cmd_options = {
        'margin-top': 3,
    }
```

If this was my view:

```
def download_report(request):
    vends = Vends.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'report_template.html', {'vends':vends})
```

*How would I generate a report of this VIEW as its rendered? Not just the template, because that would be useless?*

Comment: Is this not possible? No one knows?

Comment: Is using DJANGO-wkhtmltopdf a requirement? A normal view and python-wkhtmltopdf could get the job done.

Answer (score 6):

You can use PDFTemplateRespone instead of render_to_response.

```
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
def pdf(request, pk):   
     context = RequestContext(request)    
     template = 'test.html'

     context = {
        'variable1': variable1,
        'variable1': variable1,
        'variable1': variable1,
        'variable1': variable1

    }


    return PDFTemplateResponse(request=request, cmd_options={'disable-javascript':True}, template=template, context=context)
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like I'm 3 years late :) I put here a working code sample anyway, as reference for future needs:

**urls.py**

```
# here you must import MyPDF from [your-app-name].views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^pdf/$', MyPDF.as_view(template_name='my_template.html',
                                             filename='my_pdf.pdf'), name='pdf'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView

class MyPDF(PDFTemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyPDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['foo'] = 'BAR'
        return context
```

**my_template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ foo }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. You saved me a couple of hours

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem as yours, got everything working with rendering propetly CSS + JS but i'm also unable / don't know how to render or pass the data to get template rendered and then converted.

If someone could give a hint or point in a good direction, it would be awesome.

Comment: I am having the same problem as well :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232691/creating-pdfs-with-django-wkhtmltopdf