# Creating PDFs with django (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

Could someone please provide me with a comprehensive example of how to get a `view` in `django` to return a `PDF` using `wkhtmltopdf`. There are limited number of examples that come with `django-wkhtmltopdf` and they presume a level of knowledge I just don't have. I have looked through the source code but I can't make heads or tails of how to use it (for example whats the difference between `PDFTemplateView` and `PDFTemplateResponse`?!?)

I would be very grateful for any help.

*BTW(I'm using templates for the header and footer as well)*

**EDIT**

```
def some_view(request,sID):
    something = get_object_or_404(Something,id=sID)
    return render_to_response('something.html', {'something':something}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How would I get the following simple view to provide me with a `pdf` instead of an `html` file?

**EDIT 2**

I am currently playing around with:

```
def pdf_view(request,sID):
    template = 'pdf.html'
    something = get_object_or_404(Something,id=sID)
    context = {
        'something' : Something,
        'object_for_header_and_footer': something.object_for_header_and_footer,
    }
    cmd_options = settings.WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS

    return PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
        context=context,
        template=template,
        filename='something',
        header_template='header.html',
        footer_template='footer.html',
        cmd_options=cmd_options)
```

but I am getting `'str' object has no attribute 'update'` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py in wkhtmltopdf, line 74`. I don't know whether to starting hacking wkhtmltopdf?!?!

Comment: The normal view and PDFTemplateResponse is working for me. I didn't specify the WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference between PDFTemplateView and PDFTemplateResponse is that the view is a class-based view. And PDFTemplateResponse renders the pdf data and sets the right [response headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment). To add header and footer:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView


    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        ...
        url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='my_template.html',
                filename='my_pdf.pdf', 
                header_template='my_header_template.html', 
                footer_template='my_footer_template.html', 
                ...
                ), name='pdf'),
    )
```

Opening pdf/ in your browser will start a download of my_pdf.pdf based on the my_template.html, my_header_template.html and my_footer_template.html.

The [advanced example](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#advanced-example) shows how to subclass PDFTemplateView extending and changing the logic of PDFTemplateView. To understand what happens read [Using class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views).

Like `header_template` and `footer_template` you can define a `response_class`. Because PDFTemplateResponse is the default, you don't have to define it.

**EDIT**

The following simple view provides you with a pdf instead of an html. This is not using django-wkhtmltopdf. You could use wkhtmltopdf in your html2pdf function.

```
def some_view(request):
    t = loader.get_template('myapp/template.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'foo': 'bar'})
    html = t.render(c)
    pdf_data = html2pdf(html) # Your favorite html2pdf generator
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_data, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_filename.pdf"'
    return response
```

**EDIT 2**

A simple view with context:

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from views import MyPDFView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^pdf/', MyPDFView.as_view()),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse

class MyPDFView(View):
    template='template.html'
    context= {'title': 'Hello World!'}

    def get(self, request):
        response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                       template=self.template,
                                       filename="hello.pdf",
                                       context= self.context,
                                       show_content_in_browser=False,
                                       cmd_options={'margin-top': 50,},
                                       )
        return response
```

**EDIT 3**

If you use a DetailView, you can add the object to context:

```
url(r'^books/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', MyPDFView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),


class MyPDFView(DetailView):
    template='pdftestapp/template.html'    
    context= {'title': 'Hello World!'}
    model = Book

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
        self.context['book'] = self.get_object()

        response=PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                     template=self.template,
                                     filename ="hello.pdf",
                                     context=self.context,
                                     show_content_in_browser=False,
                                     cmd_options={'margin-top': 50,}
                                     )
        return response
```

Comment: That's fine for rendering static `.html` (I presume) but what happens if you want `def something.views.something_view(request,someID)` to render a `pdf` rather then `html`?

Comment: (& on a side note why are static `*.html` files being passed to attributes with `template` in them. It doesn't make sense?!? surely if an attribute has `template` in it it is asking for a `view`. Isn't it?!?)

Comment: I feel a bit like `User.objects.filter(clue__lt=0)`

Comment: I agree, passing a view to render a pdf would be nice. You could open a issue on their GitHub page.

Comment: Added a simple view that returns a pdf.

Comment: How do I then pass an id so I can get an object inside the `get` function? (i.e. so I can use `{% url something.views.something_view something.id %}`

Comment: Not only that but how do I use `{% url ... %}` with it?

Comment: And yes, you can just put {% url ... %} in your templates. It worked for me.

Comment: got it working!!! Now just need to get the right version of `wkhtmltopdf` (can't do headers and footers with my version :(

Comment: Update adding an object to context.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm the error indicates that you're passing string somewhere that you shouldn't.

After checking its [source code](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py#L74), I guess in `settings.py` you have `WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS` as a string, something like

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS = 'some_option_here'
```

But you should assign a dict there:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS = {
    'quiet': True,
}
```

Otherwise your code should work fine.